# Reading from file with fgetc in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

I have a file with more rows, and now, I would like to scan the 3th, from char to char. This is working, but I can't assign the chars with the (onerow) array, only the first one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32)
    #include <windows.h>
#endif

int main(void) {
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) //for latin2
    SetConsoleCP(1250);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1250);
#endif
    //char* onerow=(char*) malloc(num*sizeof(char));
    char* onerow[250];
    char c;
    int row=3, j=0;

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("proba.txt", "r");

    for (int i=0; i<=row; i++) {
        if(i!=row-1) {          //not the row we need, jump over it
            while(c!='\n')
                c=fgetc(fp);
            c='a'; //to make true while next time
        }
        if(i==row-1) {
            while(c!='\n') {    //this is what we need
                //onerow[j]=fgetc(fp);
                //onerow = (char*)realloc(onerow, ++num*sizeof(char));
                c=fgetc(fp);
                printf("%c", c); //this is working well (prints everyth.)
                onerow[j++]=c;
            }
        }
    }
    onerow[j-1]='\0';
    fclose(fp);
    printf("%s", onerow); //prints only the first charachter
    //free(onerow);
}
```

First output (%c) is good, that is the whole row. However the second output (%s) is only the row's first char (which is a number in the file... the file is a latin2 txt.)

Comment: `onerow` is an array of pointers, not an array of characters.

Comment: Aren't you getting a warning from `onerow[j++]=c;`?

Comment: Why don't you use `fgets()` to read lines?

Comment: what happens when there is no last `\n` and `fgetc` returns `EOF` ?

Comment: There is no warning, I use fgetc because of malloc what i will and should use, and the fgetc is working well, the printf(%c) shows this, and there is a \n there.

Comment: Change `onerow[j-1]='\0';` to `onerow[j]='\0';`  However, you have other issues in your code.  @Barmar and myself have pointed out.  And yes, you should be getting a warning.  You need to make sure warnings are enabled in your environment.

Comment: At `while(c!='\n')` you should get a compiler warning: uninitialised variable. You said earlier you don't get warnings: are they enabled?

Comment: Oh, yes, i have that warning (now enabled, sorry!) Everything is okay, working. Thanks for it and the tips!

Answer (score 0):

You declared `onerow` as an array of pointers to characters, you can't assign characters directly to the elements.

If you want `onerow` to be a dynamically-growing string, it should be declared as a pointer, not an array of pointers:

```
size_t rowsize = 250;
char *onerow = malloc(rowsize);
```

Then you should call `realloc()` if you get more than `rowsize` characters.

```
c = fgetc(fp);
if (j >= rowsize-1) {
    rowsize += 250;
    onerow = realloc(onerow, rowsize);
}
onerow[j++] = c;
```

And at the end you shouldn't subtract `1` from `j` when appending the null byte, it should be:

```
onerow[j] = '\0';
```

I used `rowsize-1` in the above test before `realloc()` to ensure that there will be room for the null byte (rather than doing another test here).

Comment: I'd suggest changing `c` from `char` to `int` and also testing for `EOF`.  Otherwise --> infinite loop on a file without 3 newlines.  OP's code attempts to read the 4th line and discards it -- because of `i<=row` in for loop.